# JSONP ajax response has callback sitting inside another callback and response object is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am finding that when making this ajax request if I inspect the response in chrome's developer tools it's coming back as:

```
callback(callback({...}))
```

With the inner callback referring to the one specified in jsonpCallback.  And if I try and read out the response in the success function I am told that response is undefined.

Below is the ajax request I'm making.

```
$.ajax({
    url: http://www.domain.com/cameraservice/1.0/getCameras,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        that.reset( that.parse(response.cameras.camera) );
        Vent.trigger('cameras.updated', that);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with a co-worker we determined that the issue lay in the server-side code.  He was double-wrapping the return data which resulted in there being two callback methods.